# how to calclulate offset between camera look at y position to target y position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have camera that look at target on x and z position of the target and on y target position with some offset(im in case that i can not know in advance what exactly the offset) , how to calclulate what the offset between the target y position to the y position where the camera forward actually look at ?

```
void LookAtTargetWithYoffset()
{
    transform.LookAt(new Vector3(
        target.position.x,
        target.position.y + Vector3.up.y * offset, 
        target.position.z
    ));
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The difference is what you provide yourself `offset` .. why do you need to calculate it again? Btw `Vector3.up.y` will always be `1` ^^ You could write it way shorter as simply `transform.LookAt(target.position + Vector3.up * offset);`

Comment: @derHugo im building biliard game in 3d i have states that i can rotate my camera vertically and horizontally around the cueball target(so the y offset change from time to time) and i have states when i only allowed to look at the target position plus the last y offset between the target cue ball to y position where  I looked at state before, so when im swiching to this state(when im only allowed to look at cueball target) im must to know the last y offset to look at the target with the correct offset

Comment: @ShlomoHalev When you're calculating the offset, is it guaranteed that the camera will be looking at a point at, above, or below the target? Or will it be sometimes to the side of the target? If it can be looking at the side of the target, how is the offset to be calculated?

Comment: @Ruzihm in my case its only about above the target because of in z and x axis i look at the target without offset and also my camera not going to look below the target

Comment: @ShlomoHalev Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: @Ruzihm in the case when the offset its only above yes  your answer answered to me in other cases when the offset can be also from sides or below I did not try to find a solution because I did not have such a case but if I have such a case I guess I will find a solution with the same principle

Comment: @ShlomoHalev if my answer helped, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use algebraic planes and rays to calculate this. These do not use physics raycasts so are quite performant.

```
Plane camPlane = new Plane(transform.up, transform.position);
Ray targetRay = new Ray(target.position, Vector3.up);

camPlane.Raycast(targetRay, out offset);
```

See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html for more info, especially about cases where the camera might be looking directly up or down, or if offset is negative.

Comment: hi thanks, its seems good idea but i think i need to define the normal of the plan to the normal of the camera  end set y normal plan to ziro and the position of the plan to the target position and than when i send raycast from camera forward i will hit exactly above/below the target and the offset will be the distance between the hit and the target y position

Comment: @ShlomoHalev You could send a ray from the camera along its forward but that requires an extra step of zeroing out the y component of the forward of the camera to find the normal of the plane located at the target's position. Did you actually try to use the code in this answer?

Comment: I've not checked yet but you're right I did not notice in the first look that my way is more cumbersome ,but anyway in your code i think the plan needs to be in the the camera position and the plan normal is camera up direction and than when i send the ray from the target i will get the desire point above the target  Because plan's normal its the up direction of the camera,I believe that what you meant I'm right?

Comment: @ShlomoHalev Yes, this is exactly what the code I have written in this answer does.